# document.lastModified inside a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to use JavaScript and jQuery to have the document.lastModified inside a div in my footer. I tried to create the ready event and that is below. I am not really sure if I put the script in the correct location or if I even created it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I am attempting to do:
Code a jQuery script block that includes the ready event and uses the html()
method to display the message “This page was last modified on:” and the
document.lastModified value within the new div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="javajam.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a>;</li>
<li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a>;</li>
<li><a href="music.html">Music</a>;</li>
<li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>;</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="heroroad">
</div>
<h2>Follow the Winding Road to JavaJam</h2>
<p>We're a little out of the way, but take a drive down Route 42 to JavaJam today!
Indulge in our locally roasted free-trade coffee and home-made pastries.You'll feel
right at home at JavaJam!</p>
<h3>JavaJam Coffee House features:</h3>
<ul>
<li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
<li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
<li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
<li>Open Mic Night</li>
</ul>
<div>
54321 Route 42<br>
Ellison Bay, Wi 54210<br>
<a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a>
<span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span><br>
</div>
</main>
<br>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
<a href="#">email@email.com</a>
<div>
<script>$document().ready(function(){$(“footer div”).html(‘This page was last modified on:’+document.lastModified);});</script>
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `$(document)` instead of `$document()` and don't use fancy quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put it anywhere, but best practice says the bottom or head section of of your page. instead of your question I saw one mistake in your code. you can update it using this block of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("footer div").html("This page was last modified on: "+document.lastModified);
});

<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
<a href="#">email@email.com</a>
<div></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: What mistake? Please are don't make it spot the difference game

Comment: @Satpal same thing you just write in comment

Comment: @Brett please create a new question or make it in fiddle